# FlxSprite ignore camera follow in flixel

Tags: camera, flixel

I am using flixel v2.5 and am using `FlxG.camera.follow` to get the camera to follow the player. I have a background `FlxSprite` that I don't want to move with the camera. Is there a way I can set this `FlxSprite` to stay in the same place on the screen? I would also like to have a GUI HUD that stays fixed to the screen, and was thinking I could do this the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous versions, you could set the background/HUD's scrollfactor.x and scrollfactor.y to zero. Does that still work in 2.5?

Comment: Yip, scrollfactor still works. I found that I had to set the scrollfactors on some objects in a nested group to get the effect that I needed. thanks.

Comment: When you add an object to a group, there should be an optional second parameter that makes its scrollfactor match the group's.